# Проблема с timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Поле `input type=time` — модель,  ввожу время, вывожу где нить на странице или отправляю на сервер, время на 3 часа меньше, я так понимаю это выводит чистое время.
Как зафиксировать, потому как мне нужно передать конкретное время например 3 часа, 3:20 и тп.

На странице если просто выводить ещё можно выкрутиться

```
| date:'HH:mm:ss'
```

А при отправке на сервер я просто `JSON.stringify` на модель кидаю и отправляю

Вот так ещё можно преобразовать

```
$filter('date')(this.new_quest.timelimit, 'HH:mm:ss');
```

но при переназначении

```
 this.new_quest.timelimit = $filter('date')(this.new_quest.timelimit, 'HH:mm:ss');
```

Будет ошибка Error: [ngModel:datefmt] 
Копировать объект только из-за time для отправки на сервер как то не гуд

В общем если кто то подскажет как по нормальному сделать буду благодарен, а пока сделал так:

```
var timeformat = $filter('date')(this.new_quest.timelimit, 'HH:mm:ss');
var send_to_server = JSON.stringify(this.new_quest);
send_to_server = JSON.parse(send_to_server);
send_to_server.timelimit = timeformat;
send_to_server = JSON.stringify(send_to_server);
```

Comment: можете показать пример в [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению я понимаю, как именно работает `$filter('date')`. Но думаю ваш код можно преобразовать примерно так

```
send_to_server = JSON.stringify(this.new_quest,
     function(key,val) {
       if(key=='timelimit') return $filter('date')(val, 'HH:mm:ss');
       return val;
     });
```

У JSON.stringify есть второй параметр, если он функция - то во время сериализации она вызывается для каждого ключа упаковываемого объекта и ей передается имя ключа и его значение. На выходе она должна вернуть то значение, которое надо положить в результат или `undefined`, если данный ключ надо исключить из результата.